# How to convert for loop to list comprehension syntax in python?

Tags: python

I have this code and I would like to write it in a list comprehension

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

my_dict = {}
y = 0
for x in list1:
    my_dict[x] = list2[y]
    y=y+1
print (my_dict)
```

Comment: Don't need one: `dict(zip(list1, list2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution :

```
my_dict={list1[i]:list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dict constructor with a `zip` of the two lists instead:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```